# Similar solutions but different answers

Tags: c++, string, c-strings

I am facing difficulty while solving a problem where we have to check whether a string is a subsequence of another string or not.

A man with name M is allowed to marry a woman with name W, only if M is a subsequence of W or W is a subsequence of M.

A is said to be a subsequence of B if A can be obtained by deleting some elements of B without changing the order of the remaining elements.

Example - 
john and johanna will give "YES" as output
kayla and jayla will give "NO" as output
johanna and john will give "YES" as output

My code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

bool checksub(string a, string b)
{
    int pos=0;
    for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
    {
        int flag=0;
        for(int j=pos; j<b.size(); j++)
        {
            if(b[j]==a[i])
            {
                flag=1;
                pos=j;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here

    int t;
    cin>>t;

    while(t--)
    {
        string a,b;
        cin>>a>>b;


        if(a.size()==b.size())
        {
            if(a==b)
            {
                cout<<"YES"<<endl;
            }else{
            cout<<"NO"<<endl;}
        }
        else if(a.size()>b.size()){
            if(checksub(b,a))
            {
                cout<<"YES"<<endl;
            }else{
                cout<<"NO"<<endl;
            }
        }else{
            if(checksub(a,b))
            {
                cout<<"YES"<<endl;
            }else{
                cout<<"NO"<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The editorial of the question uses a similar approach. Can anybody tell me what's wrong with my code?

The editorial solution is given below :

```
#include <cstdio>

char M[25005], W[25005];

bool contains(const char *A, const char *B){
    while(*A){
        if(*B==*A)
            B++;
        A++;
    }
    return !*B;
}

int main(){
    int T;
    scanf("%d", &T);
    while(T--){
        scanf("%s %s", M, W);
        puts(contains(M, W) || contains(W, M) ? "YES" : "NO");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Link to the problem: https://www.codechef.com/problems/NAME2

Comment: Not sure why you think your solution and the editorial solution are similar. Your code has two loops and the editorial solution has only one for instance.

Comment: When you go to the editorial you will find the approach is similar... https://discuss.codechef.com/t/name2-editorial/2022

Comment: I really don't think the approaches are similar at all. The logic of your code is hard to understand but I'm trying to find an example to show why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code produces the wrong result with input `AA BAB` because it fails to account for the fact that you need to have two `A` in the second string.

You might be able to fix it by changing `pos=j;` to `pos=j+1;` but I'm not certain.

There really is no similarity between your code and the editoral code however. Even with my suggested fix (if it does work) your code is clearly less efficient than the editorial code because it scans the input strings repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

Got the correct answer just by changing pos=j+1 instead of pos=j. Then code will become similar to the pseudocode in the editorial. Thanks, everybody for answering.